# Closed ideal in $L^1(G)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $G$ be a locally compact abelian group. Let $I$ be a right translation invariant subspace of $L^1(G)$; that means $f_x$ is in $I$ for all $f$ in $I$ and $x$ in $G$ and let $f_x(y):=f(y-x)$ and  also suppose $\phi$ be in $L^∞(G)$ that annihilates $I$; that means $\phi(g)=0$, for $g\in I$. Then by [1]
$$\int_Gf(−y)ϕ(y)dy=0$$
for every $f\in I$

.

Question:
Why does this equation is hold?  or Is this equation valid for any locally compact group?

[1] Walter Rudin, Fourier analysis on groups,1962,page 157.

Comment: I just want to know why the relationship $\int_Gf(−y)\phi(y)dy=0$
is true.

Comment: Since $\phi\in L^{\infty}(G)$ by duality of $L^{\infty}$ and that is $\phi$ annihilates $I$, we know that $\int_Gf(x)\phi(x)dx$ is equal to zero, but we cannot why this equation ,$\int_G f(-x)\phi(x)dx$, is equal to zero!